# Navigating to new page with selcted combobox item when button is click UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I want the user to select an item in a combobox and when they press a button, that they will be redirected to the specific page. How can I achieve this?

```html
<pre><Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Campus_Selector" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,414,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" PlaceholderText="Select a Campus " Width="233">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Auckland Park" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Bloemfontein" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Boksburg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Cape Town" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Durban" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Nelspruit" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Polokwane" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Port Elizabeth" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Potchefstroom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Pretoria" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Roodepoort" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Sandton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Stellenbosch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Vereeniging" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button x:Name="Navtocapus" Content="Navigate to selected Campus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,504,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Navtocapus_Click"/>

    </Grid>
```

I tried using an if statement, and I tried all the Campus_Selector.Selected(statements) if that makes sence

Comment: please also show some c# code related to what you are doing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the button is clicked just check the **Selected property** of the **combobox** and navigate accordingly.

```
private void Navtocapus_Click(object sender, args)
{
    if(Campus_Selector.SelectedIndex != -1)//just to make sure an item is selected
    {
        string item = (Campus_Selector.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Content as string;
        //use whatever your frame is to navigate to your desired page using value of item.
        frame.Navigate(typeof(YourPageClass));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Button_Click Event, make a SelectCase from Combobox.SelectedIndex,
and handle each case:

```
Select case Combobox.SelectedIndex;
case 1;
Frame.Navigate(SomePage);
case 2;
Frame.Navigate(SomeotherPage);
...
```